# Can we check complicated condition by just using List and its size as in this case?

Tags: java, list

There is a Item table, each item has a maximum of 3 different actions (act1, act2, act3), but some item only has 1 or 2 acts. Also, some item has duplicated act like item #2 has 2 entries of act3.

```
ItemID - ActionID
1 - act1
1 - act2
1 - act3
2 - act1
2 - act3
2 - act3
3 - act1
3 - act3
```

Let say we have a method to `getItemInfo(List<Integer> itemList)` to get result of item Info, the condition is that the result is only valid if each item containing all 3 acts & all items in the itemList must be appear in the result & finally there is no duplicated in the result.

```
List<Integer> itemList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
itemList.add(1);
itemList.add(3);
```

then run `getItemInfo(List<Integer> itemList)`

The Result will be valid (met all the conditions) like this example :

```
1 - act1
1 - act2
1 - act3
3 - act1
3 - act2
3 - act3
```

The Result will be invalid like this example (cos item #1 does not contain act3:

```
1 - act1
1 - act2
3 - act1
3 - act2
3 - act3
```

The Result will be invalid like this example (cos item #1 contains duplicates act2):

```
1 - act1
1 - act2
1 - act2
1 - act3
3 - act1
3 - act2
3 - act3
```

The Result will be invalid like this example (cos the result does not contain item#3):

```
1 - act1
1 - act2
1 - act3
```

So here is 1 solution, that is i put all the result in the List and check duplicated, then I check the size, ex:

```
//run via loop to put all result into a `List<String[]> resultList` 
& this `resultList` contains `String[]` like    
String[] s1={"1","act1"}
String[] s2={"1","act2"}
.....
```

Then

```
    if(!MyValidation.isDuplicated(resultList) && 
       resultList.size()==3*itemList.size() ){
          System.out.println("valid");
    }
    else{
         System.out.println("not valid");
    }
```

My simple question is that, Can `if(!MyValidation.isDuplicated(resultList) && 
       resultList.size()==3*itemList.size() ){}` be used for checking all the conditions mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: No.

decomposition:

```
 MyValidation.isDuplicated(resultList)
```

will check for any duplicates, that is ok, but

```
  resultList.size()*itemList.size()==3*itemList.size()
```

is the same as

```
 resultList.size() == 3
```

(just mathematics: if a*b=3*b then a=3) and that's too simple.

Comment: hi, sorry that is mistake, i just modified, do u think if(!MyValidation.isDuplicated(resultList) && resultList.size()==3*itemList.size() is ok enough

Comment: so u sure the is no possible way that all the conditions won't be met if using my solution. Why such complicated conditions can be validated by such a simple checking?

Comment: actually, there is no "complicated condition": you are expecting clusters of three different line items. If there are duplicates or if its not a power of three, it's wrong. Otherwise they all differ and they are in a power of three. The set of possible items is limited and this is one big constraint in your solution ("1", "2", "3"). Once this changes, your solution will break.

Comment: u need to modify ur answer cos I modified my question